# web3js - best way to make sure awaited values are received by the server even if client closes browser

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, wordpress, web3js

I have a site on wordpress that uses web3js to allow users to interact with the blockchain using client side js. The js sends values back to the server to be saved/updated in the database. I am using wordpress functions.php with ajax to save the values.

Everything works fine however, there are instances of funds being taken out of a user's wallet and the server not receiving the values which is necessary to update posts etc. It seems the most likely scenario for this is if a user closes the page/browser or interruption in the network connection.

Function example -

```
await collection.methods.buyNFT(someVariables).send({from: account, value: price})
 .on('receipt', async function(receipt) {                                                           
   await $.ajax({                                   
     url: ajaxurl,                                  
     type: 'POST',                                  
     data: {                                        
      'action': 'some_action',                                      
      'id': Id,                                     
      'txnHash': txnHash,                               
    },
  })
})
```

I'm trying to figure out what would be the best way to ensure that the values are received and saved to the database. As of now I am thinking of sending an ajax post on the contract.method's `on('sent')` function, but that's not an "official" confirmation, and I would need to setup another function to manually check each post.

After a user confirms the transaction, there's no other interaction needed on their end, and the rest of the script is just waiting for responses from the chain to update the database.

Is there a way to keep the script alive and finish, regardless if the client closes the page or loses connection?

I've also tried looking into fetch, nodejs, pm2, etc. but I'm not sure what approach to take for this. Any suggestions?